# using glide to show animated gif file with ImageView (android)

Tags: android

[image]

I make gif Files animated then, I put this one in the Application's imageview.

```
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(character6);
            Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.company_normal8).into(imageViewTarget);
```

here's code and I have no problem with apply this one.

But I have serious issue that The image have afterimage.

I made this gif file with photoshop and It have 2 frame

There's A frame and B frame.

But at android app,

A -> B -> A -> B (this is the normal one)

But My app

A -> A+B -> A -> A+b (like this afterimage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use asGif

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imgUrl)
    .asGif()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.img)
    .crossFade()
    .into(imageView);
```

**OR**

Try this if Glide is not working for you,Its working for me

```
public class GIFView extends View{

    Movie movie;
    long moviestart;

    public GIFView(Context context) throws IOException { 
        super(context);
    }
    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) throws IOException{
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) throws IOException {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void loadGIFResource(Context context, int id)
    {
        //turn off hardware acceleration
        this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        InputStream is=context.getResources().openRawResource(id);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    public void loadGIFAsset(Context context, String filename)
    {
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = context.getResources().getAssets().open(filename);
            movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (movie == null) {
            return;
        }

        long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (moviestart == 0) moviestart = now;

        int relTime;
        relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
        movie.setTime(relTime);
        movie.draw(canvas,10,10);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

XML

```
<yourpackagename.GIFView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:src="@drawable/yourgifimage"/>
```

To set the image

```
imagevw.loadGIFResource(this, R.drawable.yourgifimage);
```

Comment: I make my source like this    Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.employer_normal).asGif().into(imageViewTarget);  But into method have red line :(

Comment: I removed error But still background stacks.. I really want to remove this one

Comment: thank you for comment.. But if i use GIfview way, The image disappears,,

Comment: Fianlly I solve this problem, I have a big mistake in Gradle option. I use glide 3.5.0. The error disappears when I update to 3.8.0