# How to show gif on Glide

Tags: java, android, gif, android-glide

I want to show gif on Glide error() in recycler Adapter.
how should I do that?

I want to show a picture in Glide, and when the internet will be disconnected, I'll show a Gif, but Glide Gif will not show.
here is my glide code that just shows loading_back.gif and didn't show connection_fail.gif .

```
 RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.static_place_holder)
            .error(R.drawable.connection_fail)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .priority(Priority.HIGH);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(items.get(pos).getLinks())
            .apply(options)
            .thumbnail(Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.loading_back))
            .thumbnail(Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.connection_fail))
            .into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using glide to show animated gif file with ImageView (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319981/using-glide-to-show-animated-gif-file-with-imageview-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-library)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319981/using-glide-to-show-animated-gif-file-with-imageview-android) questions.

**build.gradle(app-level)**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
}
```

**Use of [Glide.](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)**

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imgUrl)
    .asGif()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.img)
    .crossFade()
    .into(imageView);
```